# Datacontext binding gets lost in a master detail scenario

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to build a Master/Detail scenario by using the DataGrid as master and a HexControl (ref: https://github.com/abbaye/WpfHexEditorControl) as its detail content.

I have an **ObservableCollection** where the **RowModel** class contains the properties for the DataGrid and I have a **HexEditorContent** class within the **RowModel** class, so I can create the Master/Detail pattern when the user selects a row to show the data in a HexEditor control. New rows are added via a button. Additionally, I use the Prism Framework.

The minimal example in code looks like this:

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="HexEditorTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HexEditorTest"
        xmlns:hexEditor="clr-namespace:WpfHexaEditor;assembly=WPFHexaEditor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Add Row" Click="Button_Click" Width="100"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding Acol}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding Bcol}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Header="Payload">
            <hexEditor:HexEditor DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=SelectedItem.HexEditorContent}" Stream="{Binding HexByteStream}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And its **MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ViewModel viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new ViewModel();

            DataContext = viewModel;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            viewModel.Rows.Add(new RowModel
            {
                Acol = "c",
                Bcol = "d",
                HexEditorContent = new HexEditorContent { HexByteStream = new MemoryStream(Enumerable.Repeat((byte)0, 10).ToArray(), true) }
            });
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<RowModel> Rows { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RowModel>();
    }

    public class HexEditorContent : BindableBase
    {
        private MemoryStream memStream;
        public MemoryStream HexByteStream
        {
            get { return memStream; }
            set { SetProperty(ref memStream, value); }
        }
    }

    public class RowModel : BindableBase
    {

        private string aCol;
        public string Acol
        {
            get { return aCol; }
            set { SetProperty(ref aCol, value); }
        }

        private string bCol;
        public string Bcol
        {
            get { return bCol; }
            set { SetProperty(ref bCol, value); }
        }

        private HexEditorContent hexEditor;
        public HexEditorContent HexEditorContent
        {
            get { return hexEditor; }
            set { SetProperty(ref hexEditor, value); }
        }

    }
```

Now, when I click to add a new row, the new row appears with the default data set, like:

[image]

But, when I add another row and switch back to the first row, the input of the first row is gone:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Every time I switch, the data context seems to be lost and it does never appear again...

EDIT:

Here is the Debug View of the MemoryStream

[image]

Comment: can you put a breakpoint after `viewModel.Rows.Add()` and inspect MemoryStreams after selection? I don't think selection causes it per se. Something goes wrong inside hexeditor. Does it happend if MemorySteam is not writtable?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the memorystreams. The bool writeable flag was already set.

Comment: I believe you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for it to notify the model that it has changed.